# Magento 2.2.5 Wysiwyg editor Error : Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Tags: adminform, magento-2.2.5, wysiwyg, editor

In my custom module, I integrate **Wysiwyg** editor to admin form and it is working fine. but when I insert the external image path to the editor then it will show below error.

> error: error in [unknown object].fireEvent(): event name: tinymceSetContent error message: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

But when I insert same image path to Product content then it will not be showing any error and be working fine. I don't understand what's going wrong.

Here is my code editor code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $wysiwygConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config')->getConfig();
    $fieldset->addField(
        'about_uS',
        'editor',
        [
            'name' => 'about_uS',
            'label' => __('About US'),
            'title' => __('About US'),
            'wysiwyg' => true,
            'config' => $wysiwygConfig
        ]
    );
```

---

**Edit:**

When i place same image URL under `Admin >> content >> pages` also get same error.

Can anyone help me to solve out this problem?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution after applying `'add_widgets' => false`.

Hear is my code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $wysiwygConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config')->getConfig(array('add_widgets' => false));
    $fieldset->addField(
        'about_uS',
        'editor',
        [
            'name' => 'about_uS',
            'label' => __('About US'),
            'title' => __('About US'),
            'wysiwyg' => true,
            'config' => $wysiwygConfig
        ]
    );
```

But i think this is not a proper way to solve problem, because i don't understand behind the reason of where `'add_widgets' => false` affected.

If any have a better & proper way solution then post your answer for further user. it might be helpful to other user contributor.